# Firebase "Could not find member: Value" in Swift method

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

I have a block of code that I use to retrieve some information from Firebase. However, I don't know why it won't recognize it's own enum value. I don't get this error anywhere else in my project where I call `.Value` so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong pragmatically.

Here is the code snippet:

```
func getTimerInformation() {
    let timerRef = firebaseRef.childByAppendingPath("currentEvent").childByAppendingPath("stopTime")
        timerRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
            self.dm.eventEndTime = snapshot.value
        })
}
```

[image]

Comment: What happens if you fully specify it:  `FEventType.Value` ?

Comment: @vacawama the exact same error occurs. I even looked at the implementation for FEventType and `Value` was there

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is completely misleading.

Swift closures that are 1 line long return the value of that line.  Swift is expecting that closure to return `void`, so your closure doesn't match the closure it is expecting in `observeSingleEventOfType`.  Swift at that point is terribly confused, so it doesn't know what to do with `.Value` because it is not sure what the signature of the function you are calling is.  If you add an explicit `return` line to the closure, then your closure will match the expected signature, and you will find what your **real** error is:

```
func getTimerInformation() {
    let timerRef = firebaseRef.childByAppendingPath("currentEvent").childByAppendingPath("stopTime")
    timerRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
        self.dm.eventEndTime = snapshot.value
        return
    })
}
```

The problem I believe is with your assignment.  `snapshot.value` is of type `AnyObject`.  After adding the return, you will see an error like:

> error: cannot assign a value of type 'AnyObject' to a value of type
>   'String'

Whatever that type is, you will need to convert `snapshot.value` to that type.  If `dm.eventTime` is indeed a `String` then:

```
func getTimerInformation() {
    let timerRef = firebaseRef.childByAppendingPath("currentEvent").childByAppendingPath("stopTime")
    timerRef.observeSingleEventOfType(.Value, withBlock: { (snapshot) in
        self.dm.eventEndTime = snapshot.value as! String
        return
    })
}
```

If you're expecting a number, then `snapshot.value.doubleValue` should work.